# Proper way to get a Recurring Callback on the UI thread

Tags: java, android

I would like to get a recurring call back to invalidate a view.  I am sure there is a neat way to do this.  I am currently doing this and would like a neater / better solution if possible?

```
new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        BannerButton.this.invalidate();
                    }
                });
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(50); // yields 20 fps
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

For a single shot timer on the UI thread, I do this: (But I cant find a way to do this with repeats)

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }, SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
```

[Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) looked good, but it calls on a background thread.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `View.postInvalidate()` method. This is different from `invalidate()` as you can do it from any `Thread` you want. It just posts an `invalidate()` message in the UI thread `Looper`

Concerning your second question simply post with some delay the same `Runnable` at the end of the `Runnable` in your `Handler`

Answer (score 2):

Your second try using Handler is already correct. Just store the Handler and the Runnable in a field, and then inside the run() method (possibly at the end), call again

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```